# ubuntu 10.04 command "# type php" returns nothing

Tags: php, linux, php5, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have 2 LAMP servers with ubuntu 10.04... both with php5 successfully installed.

on server1 i run the command `# type php` in terminal and the response is:

"php is /usr/bin/php"

however in server2 I run the same command and I get this:

-bash: type: php: not found

both servers have php5 installed via this:

```
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-common php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-imagick php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-mhash php5-mysql php5-pspell php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

why does server2 show "not found" while server1 if just fine?

Please help!  thanks

Comment: Is `php` in `$PATH` on the second server?

Comment: If PHP is installed in `/usr/bin` on server2 as well, try `echo $PATH` from the command prompt and see if `/usr/bin` is not in your path for some reason.

Comment: hey drew, this is the output: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games ... looks like '/usr/bin' is there

Comment: What does `type type` output?  It should say `type is a shell builtin`.

Comment: hey wallyk, yes output is: "type is a shell builtin"

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/bin/php*` show on server2? In other words, is php actually installed?

Comment: hey thomas: that return:    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Feb 10 02:04 /usr/bin/php-config -> /etc/alternatives/php-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3856 Feb  9 06:43 /usr/bin/php-config5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Feb 10 02:04 /usr/bin/phpize -> /etc/alternatives/phpize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4714 Feb  9 06:43 /usr/bin/phpize5

Answer (score 3):

found it! need to install the package that allows you to run php via the terminal.

ubuntu official documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/php5.html

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Comment: please accept your answer (when you're able to, it may need some time) to close out this question

Comment: there is still a delay. perhaps a vote up will allow this immediately?

Answer (score 1):

PHP comes in several forms (Server APIs): CLI, CGI, Apache, Java Servlet... Each of them has a separate binary.

- The `php` command is the **CLI** version, intended *only* for running scripts on your shell. Apache/LAMP *does not use* it.
- Apache uses the **Apache module** version, which comes in the `libapache-mod-php5` package and does not have a visible command.

In other words, there is nothing wrong. You're just looking for a different PHP SAPI.